# Calculating rank of a column with duplicate values over a category

Tags: r

I need to get the rank in a new column that gives rank for non zero values but also for zero and duplicate values.

```
Data Frame - 

Category    Value
A       0.105
A       0.104
A       0
A       0
A       0
B       0.206
B       0.105
B       0.104
B       0
B       0
```

What I need is -

```
    Category    Value   Rank 
    A            0.105  1
    A            0.104  2
    A            0      3
    A            0      4
    A            0      5
    B            0.206  1
    B            0.105  2
    B            0.104  3
    B            0      4
    B            0      5
```

I used this to generate sequence atleast but not giving correct values. Please be kind, I am just starting in R.

df is my dataframe

```
df$newRank <- with(df, ave(Category, Category, Value, FUN = seq_along))
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::row_number()` is a ranking function which is able to give equal numbers different ranks. For example, `row_number(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3))` will produce `1 2 3 4 5`. However, It gives the minimum number rank 1, the second-minimum number rank 2, and so on. So in your case, I do a transformation to reverse the magnitude, that is, make the smallest number largest before ranking.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Category) %>%
       mutate(Rank = row_number(max(Value) - Value))

# # A tibble: 10 x 3
# # Groups:   Category [2]
#    Category Value  Rank
#    <fct>    <dbl> <int>
#  1 A        0.105     1
#  2 A        0.104     2
#  3 A        0         3
#  4 A        0         4
#  5 A        0         5
#  6 B        0.206     1
#  7 B        0.105     2
#  8 B        0.104     3
#  9 B        0         4
# 10 B        0         5
```

---

**`with()` or `within()` Method**

```
within(df, Rank <- ave(Value, Category, FUN = function(x){
  return(dplyr::row_number(max(x) - x))
}))
```

(Please look up the difference between `with()` and `within()` in the R document)

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"),
                Value = c(0.105, 0.104, 0, 0, 0, 0.206, 0.105, 0.104, 0, 0)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, anyway I could write like - df$NewRank <- "the script" so that it assigns a new column this way?

Comment: Of course. By the way, `seq_along()` is unable to rank numbers unless the numbers have been sorted (such as your data). You can try `seq_along(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5))` and it will still give you `1 2 3 4 5`.

Answer (score 1):

using `data.table`:

```
dt=as.data.table(df)
dt=dt[order(Category,-Value),]
dt[,`:=`(Rank=seq_along(Value)),by=Category]
```

Comment: @DarrenTsai That's why I have sorted them before ranking. The `order` code will sort by `Category` ascending and `Value` descending

Comment: I'm sorry! It's my fault. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Using rleid from data.table is in my view the best option - you get a ranking, where equal values gets an equal rank.

```
# create a ranking variable, either by group or not, equal values has same ranking, using rleid()
df <- structure(list(category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"),
                value = c(0.105, 0.104, 0, 0, 0, 0.206, 0.105, 0.104, 0, 0)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt <- dt[, .SD[sample(.N, .N)]] # reorder the rows to mimic unordered case
dt <- dt[order(category, -value),]
# without grouping
dt[, rank :=  rleid(value)]
# with grouping
dt[, rank :=  rleid(value), by=category]
```

rleid can't use two variable to group by at the same time, though, so be carefull of that - if that's what you need, you have to create a new variable with the combination of those two variables yourself before using rleid().

if you want the ranks to be different, even if values of value within the grouping are the same, use the .N special function in data.table (here sorting is required beforehand):

```
# with equal rank to the same groups, using 1:.N
df <- structure(list(category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"),
                value = c(0.105, 0.104, 0, 0, 0, 0.206, 0.105, 0.104, 0, 0)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt <- dt[, .SD[sample(.N, .N)]] # reorder the rows to mimic unordered case

dt <- dt[order(category, -value),]
dt[, rank :=  1:.N, by=category]
```